# pigpio I2C error

Tags: python, pi-4, i2c, pigpio

I would like to write 16 bits of data to an I2C bus. Considering that the data to be transferred is not in a list, I am using the `pi.i2c_write_device()` function, however I get the following error:

```
    in i2c_write_device
    if len(data):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I am passing in a 16 bit value, hence the error. Here is the code I am working with:

```
import pigpio
import time

##########################################
##  I2C Initilization
##########################################

channel = 1

i2c_addr = 0b0001110  

pi=pigpio.pi()
j = pi.i2c_open(channel, i2c_addr) # open device at address i2c_addr on bus 1

###########################################
transfer_data = 2096
data = transfer_data << 4        #(16 bits needed for DAC)
pi.i2c_write_device(j, data)

sleep(3)
pi.i2c_close(j)
```

I appreciate any help with figuring this out. Please let me know if you have any questions, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `data` expects an array of bytes.

[i2c_write_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_write_device) gives the following examples.

```
pi.i2c_write_device(h, b"\x12\x34\xA8")

pi.i2c_write_device(h, b"help")

pi.i2c_write_device(h, 'help')

pi.i2c_write_device(h, [23, 56, 231])
```

Perhaps try something like

```
val = 2096 << 4

pi.i2c_write_device(h, [val&255, (val>>8)&255])
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation!! @joan